# Error: A value of type 'DioClient' can't be returned from a function with return type 'Dio'. -

Tags: flutter, interceptor, dio

I followed a tutorial on the internet just to learn how to intercept requests in flutter (Here is the link to the tutorial: https://dhruvnakum.xyz/networking-in-flutter-interceptors#comments-list). Their code seems to be working fine whereas mine can't compile. I keep having this error: **lib/data/network/dio_client.dart:7:27: Error: The method 'DioInterceptor' isn't defined for the class 'DioClient'.

- 'DioClient' is from 'package:interceptor_blog/data/network/dio_client.dart' ('lib/data/network/dio_client.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'DioInterceptor'.
  _dio.interceptors.add(DioInterceptor());**

Here is the content of my dio_client.dart file:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class DioClient {
  final _dio = Dio();

  DioClient() {
    _dio.interceptors.add(DioInterceptor());
  }

  Dio get dio => _dio;
}
```

HELP PLEASE!

Answer (score 0):

There is no DioInterceptor() method available in Dio package.

`DioClient() { _dio.interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper()); }`

Inside the InterceptorsWrapper you can modify the request, response, error as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the tutorial that you posted, the author states:

> Ways of adding Interceptor
>
> We can add interceptors in two ways :
> Using Built-in class [InterceptorsWrapper, QueuedInterceptorWrapper] and
> By extending custom class
> Let's add interceptor using the second way.
> Create a new file named dio_interceptor.dart file inside the network folder.
> Extend the custom DioInterceptor class with Interceptor class.

Have you tried creating the class DioInterceptor in your project? The author does provide an example implementation.

```
class DioInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  final _prefsLocator = getIt.get<SharedPreferenceHelper>();

  @override
  void onRequest(RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) {
    options.headers['Authorization'] = _prefsLocator.getUserToken();
    super.onRequest(options, handler);
  }

  @override
  void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {
    // TODO: implement onResponse
    super.onResponse(response, handler);
  }

  @override
  void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) {
    // TODO: implement onError
    super.onError(err, handler);
  }
}
```